# Setting a model values in jQuery from ajax call

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a cshtml page that is split into 2 forms.

That first part decides if the second is going to be an Edit or Add section.
Has options to search and then renders a table of results to select from or a button to Add which shows a hidden form with editor fields to post.

In the case of an edit, a table is loaded from an Editor template, each row has an Edit action link with id = Model.Id.

When an Edit link is clicked, jquery prevents default and captures the Id of that row, does an Ajax post to the controller passing the unique id which gets some data from the database and then returns a single row of a model and passes it back as a json.

The idea is to then `.show()` the AddEdit Section and populate the editor fields with the returned data.

For the AddEdit section, I know I can assign each

> @Html.EditorFor()

with a unique Id and then in jquery do something like

```
    success: function (data) {
           var $("#Forename").val(data.Forename);
...
```

for each one but is that the correct way of doing it? It seems a bit long winded.

Is there simply a way to populate the form model (which is a view model) with the returned data?

I have called Editor templates from partial views before to display rows of data but not like this as if the user clicks the add button instead of the edit i want the form to have the editor fields, but of course empty...

Edit.

Moved the html of the AddEdit section into a _PartialView and now return a model from an Ajax call and populate the partial view

```
success: function (partialViewResult) {
                                $("#PartialDiv").html(partialViewResult);
```

seems much cleaner and a lot less code!

also had problems returning dates in the json object and assigning each editor one by one, this populates as expected.

Comment: `EditorFor()` already creates a unique `id` attribute (based on the name of the property). You can always write a script that loops each property in your object and finds the corresponding element with the matching `id` attribute and update its value

Comment: Thanks,  I have only just become aware of EditorTemplates so wasn't sure perhaps if there was another form of those for single rows of data that is a  better practice.  

Is there a way to set the value of an @Html.HiddenFor() - naturally you wouldn't want to edit that but if you were to then do a normal form post that would be needed.. .

Comment: Sorry, you sure what your mean. If you have `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.SomeProperty)` the `$('#SomeProperty').val(someValue)` will set its value.

Comment: Yeah. thanks I had a space after the name between the end ' - that's why it wasn't setting.